# How reliable or trustworthy are LTSPICE demo circuits?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, schematics, ltspice

I'm looking at a few switching power supplies and one of the demo .asc files for the particular controller I was looking at really seems to fit my requirements.

Can I use their schematics in designs as is or are their some hidden 'gotchas' between what they demo vs real life ?

**Edit**

The controller I am considering using is the [LT3748](http://www.linear.com/product/LT3748) and the LTSPICE model I was looking at is [LT8309 & LT3748 Demo Circuit - 60W, 12V Output, Isolated Telecom Supply (36-72V to 12V @ 5A](http://www.linear.com/docs/44615)

For those that do not have LTSPICE and just want to see the schematic
[image]

Comment: I'm confused by your link - it opens an ascii file but the description implies it is a 60 watt supply.

Comment: @Andyaka its to be opened with LTSPICE. If you go to the first link, towards the right of the page, you will see LTSPICE demo circuits. It's the last link.

Comment: The first link is for the LT3748. I'm talking about this link: "LT8309 & LT3748 Demo Circuit - 60W, 12V Output, Isolated Telecom Supply (36-72V to 12V @ 5A" - why not cut and paste the circuit diagram?

Comment: @Andyaka do you have LTSPICE on your machine ? If you do, then  open that .asc file using LTSPICE. Otherwise, its just a textfile that is not really useful.

Comment: No I don't - I use microcap - is it the 60 watt circuit diagram shown in the LT8309 data sheet?

Comment: @Andyaka the file may be useless to you then. It's meant for those who use LTSPICE. I'll post schematics in sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my experiences, all **simulator** are just simulator, they rely on how precise your models are, and how precise your circuits are, such as if you take all the parasitic factors into consideration. This is particularly true for power supply designs.

In my opinion, LT's demo design (not just LTSpice demo circuit, i mean demos with demo board) usually have high quality. So i recommend you to reference their demo boards design. I think them are more reliable than the LTSpice demo circuit.

In your posted .asc file, you'd better go to the similar demo board: [DC1961A - LT8309ES5/LT3748EMS Isolated Demo Board | 36V ≤ VIN ≤ 72V; VOUT = 12V @ 5A](http://www.linear.com/product/LT3748#demoboards).

---

**Update:**

I don't mean **simulator** has no use, they are very useful indeed, they can help you to verify your ideas before throwing so much money. But if you want to find a **reliable** reference demo, demo board may be more **reliable**.

Comment: I've seen a video where Dave Jones from Eevblog discussed how the reference designs in a linear product was not that good and didnt work. That's why I was asking. But yes, I should be looking at demo boards more. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the LT8309 data sheet there is this diagram of a 12V 5A converter: -

[image]

Clearly there are several differences between the LTSpice circuit and the data sheet (subtle value differences it seems) but does this make LTSpice's simulation files any less reliable than the actual model of an op-amp in (say) TINA or any other simulation software?

I don't think so - the simple bottom line rule is understand what the circuit is intended to do and how it does it then check that the simulation to see that it functionally works but don't have great expectations of understanding performance limitations; these are usually better in simulation and can give false impressions that a circuit will have better performance when actually built.

One thing that simulators don't do very well is simulate what your PCB actually does. Sure, thy have "globals" for tracks inductance, ground capacitance and resistance but anything like inter-track capacitance is beyond the understanding of the software and you'd have to force parasites between nets to do this.